# How to run a function in a r loop

Tags: r, loops, apply

I have a dataframe with a set of genomic co-ordinates. I wish to find genes around those co-ordinates using `nearest.gene()` which print result one at a time. I have been struggling to run the function in a loop:

```
apply(gene_lst, 1, function (x) nearest.gene(chr=gene_lst$Chr, pos=gene_lst$Pos))
      1       2       3       4       5       6       7       8       9      10 
"ACBD3" "ACBD3" "ACBD3" "ACBD3" "ACBD3" "ACBD3" "ACBD3" "ACBD3" "ACBD3" "ACBD3"
```

It is overwriting the first output for the next nine co-ordinates. 
Is there a better way to run this function?

Comment: In your `apply` function, you didn't pass `x` into your function `nearest.gene()`

Comment: Thanks for pointing that out.

Comment: Does it solve the problem? Hopefully it works well...

Comment: Yes, it did. Thanks again for your help.

Comment: That's great! If you think my answer is helpful, please feel free to upvote/accept it. Thanks :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess you can have a try with the following code, where you should pass `x` into your function `nearest.gene()`

```
apply(gene_lst, 1, function (x) nearest.gene(chr=x["Chr"], pos=x["Pos"]))
```